# Can we have multiple Java SDKs in one machine?

Tags: java, sdk, version

Can I have multiple java SDK versions installed on my machine?

Java 1.4
Java 2
Java 6
Java 7

please advise as I have to develop solutions for Maximo in Java 1.4 and Java 2
Plus I want to learn development on Java 6 and 7

Thanks.

Comment: >Java 1.4 and Java 2 Plus
What do you mean with "Java 2 Plus"?
From Java 1.2 to Java 1.5 (exclusive), Java is called Java 2 -> Java 1.4 _is_ "Java 2 Plus"...

Answer (score 6):

> Can I have multiple java SDK versions installed on my machine?

### Yes

But make sure you use right path in your projects. It will be better to use some IDE like **Eclipse**. It will handle jdk path problems for you.

---

Java 1.4 is very old, try to shift to new one as soon as possible.

Comment: +1: Java 5.0 is also very old and if you are learning a new version of Java I wouldn't bother with Java 6 either. Java 7 is likely to be the best choice unless you have to use an older version.

Answer (score 6):

Yes,you can.
You need change environment variable Normally JAVA_HOME variable.
So you can use another variable.
eg.

```
JAVA_HOME='/home/jdk1.8.0_45'
JAVA_7='/home/jdk1.7.0_60'
JAVA_6='/home/jdk1.6.0_34'
```

Add path variable

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_7/bin
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_8/bin
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to have only one version in PATH at a time?

Comment: @3pitt The problem with having only one version of Java in the path at a time is that you might only be able to find one version of Java.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Just use full path names when invoking `javac`, `java`, etc. or set your PATH environment variable to point to the appropriate `jdk/bin` location.

The IDEs usually allow defining multiple JDKs/JREs, and you can choose which one to use for every project.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you can install as many Java SDKs as you want. When you develop you just use the JDK you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. JDK is merely a directory somewhere on your disk. So you can easily download and unpack all the versions you want, and run `java` and `javac` from the directory you're currently interested in.

IDEs will do all the messy stuff for you: just let them know where the unpacked JDKs are, and choose a JDK in project's or module's settings.

PS. Java 1.4 *is* Java 2. Java 2 is actually an umbrella name for 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4

Comment: Does the JDK...exe really just unzip and copy files to a folder? No registry entries, no nothing else?

Comment: It can set up registry entries for itself, but most of those are tagged with a specific version, and therefore do not affect each other. The system-wide settings are the version to be used by the Java plug-in, file associations, etc — nothing you would need for development or experiments.

Answer (score 1):

I attach some pics as how I configured VS code to work with two different versions of Java in one machine

[1-Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKt0U.png)

[2-Configuration inside VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeNog.png)

[3-Configuration inside VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb5Bj.png)

[4-Configuration inside VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1biTk.png)

Comment: Please assume that I am blind and that my screenreader cannot interpret your pictures. I.e. please in addition to your pictures, describe your solution.