# Can't install JDK 8 in windows 10

Tags: java, windows, java-8

I just had a computer with windows 10 already installed. For a project I need JDK 6 and JDK 8. I was able to download the first one. On the other hand, when I try to install the second I do not arrive it is just after the validation below nothing is displayed.

[image]

Thanks for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a source folder of openJDK.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye use : [Can we have multiple Java SDKs in one machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414350/can-we-have-multiple-java-sdks-in-one-machine)

To know whether jdk is installed or not try :

Go to control pannel > Program and Features and check if Java /JDK is listed there
or

1. Open your command prompt in Wndows (cmd)
2. Type “java -version“

Comment: There can be multiple versions of the JRE installed with only one's bin file on the PATH.  To see what JDK, try javac -version or look at the contents of the PATH environment variable to see if there are any references to java.

Comment: I hava already installed the JDK 6. I don't added the JDK6 to the class path so for that when I try "java -version" I have the message "'java' is not recognized as an internal command"

Comment: You need to configure your environment variables, JAVA_HOME and PATH.

JAVA_HOME must contain the path to java, and you should add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to PATH

Comment: @SBifi I think you need to read the question an other time. I can't install the JDK 8.
When I execute the setup nothing happens.
I try 32 and 64bits setups and I changed the update but the problem still persist.